# Ideas to decrease search time in Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm using the thinking sphinx gem my queries are taking about 45 seconds to complete (13 Million records, the folder containing the indexes is 1.1GB). I'm assuming I have something configured incorrectly (first time Sphinx user).  Anyway let me know if you see anything that looks amiss. Here is my configuration:

```
define_index do
  indexes :name
  indexes :summary
  indexes :tag_list

  indexes categories.name, :as => :category_name

  has "RADIANS(lat)",  :as => :latitude,  :type => :float
  has "RADIANS(lng)",  :as => :longitude,  :type => :float

  set_property :field_weights => {
    :name           => 8,
    :summary        => 6,
    :category_name  => 5,
    :tag_list       => 3
  }
  set_property :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::ResqueDelta
  set_property :ignore_chars => %w(' -)
end
```

Here is an example query:

```
Location.search('Restaurant',
                :geo => [0.5837843098436726,-1.9560609568879357],
                :latitude_attr => "latitude",
                :longitude_attr => "longitude",
                :with => {"@geodist" => 0.0..4000.0},
                :include => :categories,
                :page => 1,
                :per_page => 100)
```

My Log shows:

```
Sphinx Query (43066.3ms)  restaurant
Sphinx  Found 467 results
```

I'll keep digging through the docs and trying stuff!

UPDATE: my development.sphinx.conf

```
indexer
{
}

searchd
{
    listen = 127.0.0.1:9312
    log = /project_path/log/searchd.log
    query_log = /project_path/log/searchd.query.log
    pid_file = /project_path/log/searchd.development.pid
}

source location_core_0
{
    type = pgsql
    sql_host = localhost
    sql_user = user
    sql_pass = pass
    sql_db = db_name
    sql_query_pre = UPDATE "business_entities" SET "delta" = FALSE WHERE "delta" = TRUE
    sql_query_pre = SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'
    sql_query = SELECT "business_entities"."id" * 1::INT8 + 0 AS "id" , "business_entities"."name" AS "name", "business_entities"."summary" AS "summary", "business_entities"."tag_list" AS "tag_list", "business_entities"."id" AS "sphinx_internal_id", 0 AS "sphinx_deleted", CASE COALESCE("business_entities"."type", '') WHEN 'Location' THEN 2817059741 WHEN 'Group' THEN 2885774273 WHEN 'BraintreeBusiness' THEN 28779289 WHEN 'InvoicedBusiness' THEN 1440117572 ELSE 2817059741 END AS "class_crc", COALESCE("business_entities"."type", '') AS "sphinx_internal_class", RADIANS(lat) AS "latitude", RADIANS(lng) AS "longitude" FROM "business_entities" WHERE ("business_entities"."type" = 'Location') AND ("business_entities"."id" >= $start AND "business_entities"."id" <= $end AND "business_entities"."delta" = FALSE AND "business_entities"."type" = 'Location') GROUP BY "business_entities"."id", "business_entities"."name", "business_entities"."summary", "business_entities"."tag_list", "business_entities"."id", "business_entities"."type"
    sql_query_range = SELECT COALESCE(MIN("id"), 1::bigint), COALESCE(MAX("id"), 1::bigint) FROM "business_entities" WHERE "business_entities"."delta" = FALSE
    sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
    sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
    sql_attr_uint = class_crc
    sql_attr_float = latitude
    sql_attr_float = longitude
    sql_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
    sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM "business_entities" WHERE "id" = (($id - 0) / 1)
}

index location_core
{
    source = location_core_0
    path = /project_path/db/sphinx/development/location_core
    morphology = stem_en
    charset_type = utf-8
    ignore_chars = ', -
    enable_star = 1
}

source location_delta_0 : location_core_0
{
    type = pgsql
    sql_host = localhost
    sql_user = user
    sql_pass = pass
    sql_db = db_name
    sql_query_pre = 
    sql_query_pre = SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'
    sql_query = SELECT "business_entities"."id" * 1::INT8 + 0 AS "id" , "business_entities"."name" AS "name", "business_entities"."summary" AS "summary", "business_entities"."tag_list" AS "tag_list", "business_entities"."id" AS "sphinx_internal_id", 0 AS "sphinx_deleted", CASE COALESCE("business_entities"."type", '') WHEN 'Location' THEN 2817059741 WHEN 'Group' THEN 2885774273 WHEN 'BraintreeBusiness' THEN 28779289 WHEN 'InvoicedBusiness' THEN 1440117572 ELSE 2817059741 END AS "class_crc", COALESCE("business_entities"."type", '') AS "sphinx_internal_class", RADIANS(lat) AS "latitude", RADIANS(lng) AS "longitude" FROM "business_entities" WHERE ("business_entities"."type" = 'Location') AND ("business_entities"."id" >= $start AND "business_entities"."id" <= $end AND "business_entities"."delta" = TRUE AND "business_entities"."type" = 'Location') GROUP BY "business_entities"."id", "business_entities"."name", "business_entities"."summary", "business_entities"."tag_list", "business_entities"."id", "business_entities"."type"
    sql_query_range = SELECT COALESCE(MIN("id"), 1::bigint), COALESCE(MAX("id"), 1::bigint) FROM "business_entities" WHERE "business_entities"."delta" = TRUE
    sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
    sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
    sql_attr_uint = class_crc
    sql_attr_float = latitude
    sql_attr_float = longitude
    sql_attr_string = sphinx_internal_class
    sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM "business_entities" WHERE "id" = (($id - 0) / 1)
}

index location_delta : location_core
{
    source = location_delta_0
    path = /project_path/db/sphinx/development/location_delta
}

index location
{
    type = distributed
    local = location_delta
    local = location_core
}
```

Comment: Could you please post sphinx.conf here.

Comment: If you do post your configuration file, make sure you remove database credential details (username and password) from it.

Comment: ok, posted my development.sphinx.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem - The records happen to be in an STI table but I only want to index those of type Location (Location doesn't have any descendants). Of the 13 million records in this table 99.99984% (seriously) of them are of Location type. The SELECT DISTINCT type FROM business_entities query was taking way too long (even with an index). The tricky part was noticing this since the log was reporting the Sphinx Query lasting 84 seconds but it was really the predatory SQL queries that were the problem:

```
SQL (43647.1ms)  SELECT DISTINCT type FROM business_entities
SQL (39857.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT type FROM business_entities

Sphinx Query (84173.0ms)  restaurant
```

So I monkey patched Thinking Sphinx in an initializer to return the only type I care about:

```
module ThinkingSphinx
  class Source
    module SQL
      def type_values
        ['Location']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

https://gist.github.com/1603565

Comment: You could also add this as part of the WHERE clause in the Sphinx configuration - the following in your define_index block should do the trick: `where "business_entities.type = 'Location'"`

Comment: Also: I'd recommend putting a database index on that type column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know precisely why it's running so slow for a search, but I'd start by simplifying things in your query, and adding back complexity bit by bit, to see if anything in particular is the cause. So, first:

```
Location.search('Restaurant')
```

Then perhaps:

```
Location.search('Restaurant', :per_page => 100)
```

And so on. Don't forget that `:field_weights` in your index definition will have an effect as well.

All that said, I'm not spotting anything particularly odd with what you're doing, and 43 seconds for a search (or anything close to that) is something I've not come across before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pat, I just tried the simple query - it takes a little longer - I've tried removing the field weights from the index and it has no effect. I removed the index I have on an association and that makes building the index take less time. I'll keep trying stuff...